# Prove that $ I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4 $ are concyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, plane-geometry

**Problem**:

> $ ABCD $ is  a tangential quadrilateral and $ P $ is a point such that $ PA=PC, PB=PD . $
>   Let $ I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4 $ be the incenter of $ \triangle PDA, \triangle PAB, \triangle PBC, \triangle PCD $, respectively $ . $
>
> Prove that $ I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4 $ are concyclic

An interesting and similar problem can be found here, with solution: http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2011volume11/FG201108.pdf.

[image]

Comment: What's the source for this problem?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/htdocs/dcforum/DCForumID6/415.shtml

Comment: @geromty Nice Question. +1

Comment: @Geromty Please see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405374

Answer (score 2):

**Proof of the Conjecture from the Hyacinthos Group $9022$**:

---

Reproducing here two associated theorems and their proofs to prove the Christopher Bradley Conjecture:-

$\varsigma 1$. $\color{green}{\text{Triangle Lemmata:}}$

Consider $\triangle ABC$ and a point $P$ on side $AC$. Let the incircles of $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle PBC$ have centres $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The incircle of $\triangle ABC$ touches $AC$ at $U$. Then,

*Theorem $1$*: The points $P$ and $U$ lie on the circle with diameter $XY$.
*Theorem $2$*: The point $U$ lies on the internal common tangent of the incircles of triangles $PAB$ and $PBC$ different from the line $BP$.

$\color{red}{\text{Proof of theorem 2:}}$ Let $U$ be the point where the internal common tangent of the incircles entered at $X$ and $Y$ different from $BP$ meets $AC$. We will show that the incircle of $\triangle ABC$ touches $AC$ at $U$.

Let the internal common tangents of the incircles of triangles $PAB$ and $PBC$ touch these circles at $X'$ and $Y'$ respectively. As the internal common tangents to two circles have equal length, we get $X'Y'=X''Y''$ where $X''$ and $Y''$ are points where the incircles of triangles $PAB$ and $PBC$ touch $BP$. Thus, we have, $$PX''-PY''=X''Y''=X'Y'= UY'-UX'$$ If $J$ and $K$ are the points where the incircles of triangles $PAB$ and $PBC$ touch $AC$, then the fact that the two tangent segments from a point to the circle are equal in length gives us $PX''=PJ, PY''=PK,UX'=UJ,UY'=UK$. Using the fact that $PJ=KJ-PK$ and $UK=KJ-UJ$ gives us $PK=UJ$. Thus, $$AU=AJ+UJ=AJ+PK=(AB+AP-BP)/2 + (BP+CP-BC)/2 = (AB + AC-BC)/2$$ and $U$ is the point of tangency to the incircle of $\triangle ABC$ with side $AC$. This proves the theorem.

$\color{red}{\text{Proof of theorem 1:}}$ Now the points $X$ and $Y$ lie on the two angle bisectors of the angle formed by the lines $AC$ and $UX'Y'$ (because both of these lines touch the two incircles). Hence, $\angle{XUY} = 90^\circ$ and $U$ lies on the diameter $XY$. Using the same reasoning, for line $BP$ instead of $UX'Y'$ proves the other part, ultimately proving the theorem.

---

$\varsigma 2.\color{green}{\text{The Conjecture:}}$

Let $ABCD$ be a circumscribed quadrilateral with the incentre $O$. The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $P$. Let $X,Y,Z,W$ be the incentres of the triangles $PAB, PBC, PCD, PDA$ respectively and $(X), (Y), (Z), (W)$ be the respective incircles. Then we have to prove that $X, Y, Z, W$ are concyclic.

$\color{red}{\text{Proof of the Conjecture:}}$ Call $(O)$ the incircle of the quadrilateral $ABCD$, its centre being $O$. Let $(A'), (B'), (C'), (D')$ be the incircles of triangles $DAB, ABC, BCD, CDA$ where $A', B', C', D'$ are their respective centres. We make use of a well-known fact about circumscribed quadrilaterals that: *the incircles $(A')$ and $(C')$ of triangles $DAB$ and $BCD$ touch $BD$ at one point $T$.*

The incircles $(B')$ and $(D')$ of triangles $ABC$ and $CDA$ touch $AC$ at one point $U$. The point $T$ lies on $A'C'$; moreover the points $T$ and $R$ divide $A'C'$ harmonically, since $T$ is the internal centre of similitude of $(A')$ and $(C')$ and $R$ their external centre of similitude.

Now we can apply theorem $1$ to $\triangle ABC$ and the point $P$ on the side $AC$. Thus, points $P$ and $U$ lie on the circle with diameter $XY$. Hence, the points $X, Y, P, U$ are concyclic and $RX\times RY = RP\times RU$. Similarly, $RZ\times RW = RP\times RU$, and thus, $RX\times RY =RZ\times RW$, and the points $X,Y,Z,W$ are concyclic. This proves the theorem.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is different my problem

Comment: @geromty In your PDF, it is clearly mentioned that the problem you wanted to prove is the Bradley conjecture. It is just that the proof uses different notations for the incenters $I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4$ as $X,Y,Z,W$. Do not worry, All is fine.

Comment: @geromty Also see Takahiro Waki's link.

Comment: I take the pdf hope someone can kown this problem background.the Op is different it,because my problem the point $p$ is not diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meet it! and I think it's hard to this Conjecture from the Hyacinthos Group,at all Thank you for you answer